# show the value of javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

i want to print the value of a javascript function on screen. how do i do that? sorry, im new to javascript. This is what i have done so far...

```
< button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ');">Engaged< /button> // i wanna print the value of engaged here.

var eng = 0;  
function myFunction( i,txt ){  
var plural;  
if ( i != 1 ) plural = "s.";  
else plural = ".";  
alert(txt + i + " time" + plural);  
}
```

the value of engaged is incremented each time i click on it and is shown in the alert box. but i want to show it near to the buton. is there a way to do it?? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element near the button say:

```
   <div id="display"></div>
```

and your function can write to this like this:

```
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = txt + i + " time" + plural;
```

---

So based on the comment below You can pass another parameter to your function. The ID of the element to update.

```
function myFunction( i,txt, elemid ){  
  var plural;  
    if ( i != 1 ) plural = "s.";  
  else plural = ".";  
   document.getElementById(elemid).innerHTML = txt + i + " time" + plural;  
}
```

Then each button can call the function with the name of the element to update.

e.g.

```
  <button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ', 'display_engaged');">Engaged</button> <div id="display_engaged"></div>
```

And each button will have a corresponding element.

Comment: @Vincent - You have a slight semantic issue with your div markup.

Comment: thanks, it worked but i have like 5 buttons. i want the display to stay. < button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ');">Engaged< /button> < button onclick="nothome += 1; myFunction(nothome,'Not Home: ');">Not Home< /button> etc.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @Phphelp Do you mean that you want the same effect by all buttons? Or does each button have their own count?

Comment: one more question, is there any way to insert that to the database?? thanks for you time...

Comment: @Phphelp Not directly. You will need to give some more details to get some advice on how to put the value in a database. But since that is a whole new question why not ask another question with the details of your application such as what server side technology you are using etc. I'm sure yyou will get a lot of advice about it.

Answer (score 2):

Put something like a `<span id="spanID"></span>` next to your button

and then use the following javascript

```
document.getElementById('spanID').innerHTML = txt + i + " time" + plural";
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked but i have like 5 buttons. i want the display to stay. < button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ');">Engaged< /button> < button onclick="nothome += 1; myFunction(nothome,'Not Home: ');">Not Home< /button> etc.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly, but multiple `<span>`'s with diffrent `id` should work fine.

Comment: thanks, one more question, is there any way to insert that to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that easily.

After your button declaration, add a span tag with a unique id, such as:

```
<button ..>
<span id="engaged_value"></span>
```

And replace your alert with:

```
document.findElementById('engaged_value').innerHtml = txt + i + " time" + plural;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but i have like 5 buttons. i want the display to stay. < button onclick="eng += 1; myFunction(eng,'Engaged: ');">Engaged< /button> < button onclick="nothome += 1; myFunction(nothome,'Not Home: ');">Not Home< /button> etc.

Comment: pass the ID of the span tag you want to access within myFunction, such as:
myFunction(eng, 'Engaged', 'spanID');

Comment: thanks, one more question, is there any way to insert that to the database?

Comment: yeah, write some server side code and either use an ajax request (check jQuery POST method), or update some values in a form and submit it with the button.